# I am trying to combine (merge) four columns in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

The columns are: Street address, City, State, and zip.  I received the sheet this way, but need the data combined in one column.  There are 200 rows of data, so I don't want to have to retype everything!

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `=CONCATENATE` function to do this.

Let's say you have your data in columns A, B, C, and D then in column E (the first row of the data, which will say is E2) enter the function:

```
=CONCATENATE(A2," ",B2,", ",C2," ",D2)
```